# multiple virtual hosts apache: access from outside LAN?

Tags: apache, webserver

I've configured 2 virtual hosts on my server (servername.dyndns.org). 
How can I access it from outside LAN?

This is my configuration:

**1st Virtual Host**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName website1.local
   DocumentRoot /var/www/website1
   DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
   <Directory "/var/www/website1">
       AllowOverride All
       Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**2nd Virtual Host**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName website2.local
   DocumentRoot /var/www/website2
   DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
   <Directory "/var/www/website2">
       AllowOverride All
       Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**File Hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost 
127.0.0.1   website1.local
127.0.0.1   website2.local
```

Inside LAN, I can access single virtual host digiting website1.local or website2.local. Outside, if I digit servername.dyndns.org, I reach the default welcome index of apache or the last in the hosts file!

Thanks.

Comment: What URLs are you using to reach those servers from outside of LAN?

Comment: servername.dyndns.org, but I reach only the apache default index page!

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure `/etc/hosts` or `/Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts` on your client computer to reach those virtual hosts:
`<server-ip>   website1.local`
`<server-ip>   website2.local`